# dynamically calculating css align at run time without using javascript/jquery

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a dynamic table generation. so width varies. Now I have to make my first 2 columns sticky which can be done by `css nth-child` the problem occurs when `overflow` is `scroll` and they start overlapping on each other. In order to solve this I must calculate `left` of first column and then subtract from table's 100% so that It can be aligned next to first column. css `calc()` can be used here but again. I am unable to calculate `left` of first column in first place.

Here is my CSS

```
td:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9999;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
    left: 300px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: #fafafa;
    border-right: 1px solid silver;
}

th:nth-child(1) {
    left: 0;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 9999;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
    left: 300px;
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

and here is my fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/toxicLamba/pjresLw3/27/

Now in order to reproduce the problem when I change `width` to `300%` it breaks (currently only case to make it reproduce able)
`<table width="200%" style="overflow:scroll">`

can this be solved with pure css.

Any help will be appreciated.

**Update**

```
$('table tr').each(function() {
  $('table tr').find('td:lt(2)').css('position', 'sticky').css('background', '#fafafa').css('left', '0');
})
```

is working fine as it is working but second column is overlapping first one as both have same `z-index` and when navigated to next page. It stops working, jquery `on(load/ready/change)` not working on dynamic content

Comment: There are other ways around but "CSS can't be used to calculate an elements height or width or anything. `calc` is just meant to execute mathematic calculations"

Comment: so is there any way I can resolve this

Comment: @user_xyz.LOL But table column widths are very dynamic; their widths are final only after the whole table has been drawn. In other words, you can only start to make decisions based on these widths after everything is done loading. That is, the answer is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

honestly speaking writing CSS property left: 300px it won't be a good idea you may have a workaround in CSS but You should also focus on the hardcoding values of CSS properties as well so better use jquery for calculating left which will be dynamic

Comment: `better use jquery for calculating left which will be dynamic` can you guide me how

Answer (score 0):

So I had to do a workaround and it is working

**Code**

```
var widthOfZerothElement;
 $('table tr').each(function(index) {
   if (index == 0) {
     widthOfZerothElement = $('table tr').find('td:eq(0)').outerWidth();
     $('table tr').find('td:eq(0)').css('position', 'sticky').css('background', 'red').css('left', 0);
   }
   if (index == 1)
     $('table tr').find('td:eq(1)').css('position', 'sticky').css('background', 'red').css('left', widthOfZerothElement);
 });
```